# How To Count Objects In Header File?

Tags: objective-c, object, count, numbers, nsmutablearray

novice Objective-C programmer here.

Could you please tell me a way to count the number of objects in the header file that I've provided properties for?

I've declared several arrays and I don't want to hardcode their number (e.g. [self objectCount].

The header file is UITableViewController, I've declared four NSMutableArrays and I've given them properties (e.g. set up getters and setters).

Will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.object count];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but unfortunately it doesn't work :( It says "Request for member 'object' in something not a structure or union". Maybe UITableViewController doesn't support 'object'?

Comment: Yeah, but the object should be your array.. [self."object" count]; counts the amount of objects in your array.. so you have to change "object" to the name of your array.